# Problems booting Linux via USB 3.0 port on a Dell laptop

Tags: linux, boot, usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a problem with booting any live Linux distribution from a USB 3.0 flash drive (Kingston DataTraveler 100 G3 16 GB) on my on Dell Inspiron 7520 laptop running the latest BIOS version (A11).

When I do the same with USB 2.0 flash drive (Philips)—using Universal USB Installer 1.9.5.8 to create bootable USB flash drive—everything works fine. I go into boot manager and choose to boot from USB and it works.

But when I do it with the USB 3.0 flash drive and go into boot manager I don’t see option to boot from that USB 3.0 flash drive but instead it’s detected a a “Diskette Drive.” And when I try to boot from it, then I will see name of Linux distribution on the screen and then it freezes.

I have tried this with several Linux distributions but no success.

Comment: I would dd the first 100MB of the Stick, and then try to create again.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a problem with xHCI support of your live system. It must include the `xhci-hcd` kernel module in its initramfs for proper USB3 support, otherwise you will experience a freeze during boot or other strange problems.

There has been a [related bug report for Ubuntu.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/565047)

Answer (score 0):

Does the USB you created boot on any other computer successfully? Might not have been created properly, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick for other creation strategies, sometimes one doesn't work when another will, same drive & iso.
 I prefer the multi-boot USB method described on [pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-via-grub2-using-linux/) (they have great windows tools too), or [here on ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive).

Or if it does boot ok on other computers, then it's probably a setting somewhere in your BIOS, maybe it's treating USB devices like floppys instead of hard drives. It's not a **Windows 8 EFI/UEFI** laptop is it? If so see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Or I've seen some reported problems booting from any USB3, ports might've the problem, I *think* the USB3 drives would work if plugged into a USB2 port...

Comment: Well, I just tried to boot it on another laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad) and it worked without problems. For the BIOS, it's not Win 8 EFI/UEFI. I tried to switch from Legacy to UEFI but no effect. For the USB 2 ports, apparently Inspiron 7520 doesn't have USB 2 port ...

Comment: Either something mysterious in the BIOS, or it just does not like that usb...